# How to make viewcontroller as popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have created ViewController which has 0-0-0-0 constrains from superview.
And I recently got a task make this ViewController like a popup as shown in picture.

As you can see this white background which is my ViewController has some margins from left-right-top-bottom and shows some part of other ViewController.

How do I create this view in a quick way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have given constraints in storyboard and not by programmatically, Then at the time giving constraints if the set to margin checkbox is checked, then possibly you have this space, which default margin to the screen.. :)